# Mostrar el porcentaje de 100 números aleatorios que sean múltiplos de 5

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms, random

Hola estoy intentado hacer un programa que muestre 10 números aleatorios en un listbox y me muestre en un label el porcentaje de números que son múltiplos de 5
hasta ahora solo pude hacer que se muestre 100 numeros en el listbox pero no logro mostrar el porcentaje en el label ¿alguien sabe como se puede hacer?
el código que hice hasta ahora es este:

```
lstNumeros1.Items.Clear();

            lblRespuesta.Text = String.Empty;



            double i = 0;
            // Codifique
            for (short intValor = 0; intValor < 100; intValor++)
            {
                intNumeros[intValor] = objRandom.Next(0,100);

                    lstNumeros1.Items.Add(intNumeros[intValor]);

                    i++;
            }

            lblRespuesta.Text = i.ToString() + "%";
```

Comment: Para poder ayudarte, pone el código de lo que estas intentando, de esa manera va a ser más fácil ayudarte, saludos

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Hola ya edite el tema con el código que hice hasta ahora

Answer (score 1):

Si ya tienes el listado de números, para calcular el porcentaje de los que son múltiplos de 5 es sencillo. Para hacerlo, símplemente tienes que recorrer el listado e ir viendo si el número módulo 5 es igual a 0.

Voy a cambiar la manera de rellenar el listado, lo haces de una manera un poco rara. Con los cambios que te he comentado, quedaría algo así:

```
IList<int> lisNum = new List<int>();  //Este es el listado de numeros
lstNumeros1.Items.Clear();

lblRespuesta.Text = String.Empty;

// Rellenamos el listado con 100 valores de 0 a 100.
for (int i=0; i<100; i++)
{
    int num = objRandom.Next(0,100);
    lisNum.Add(num);  //Rellenamos el listado y el listbox con los mismos valores
    lstNumeros1.Items.Add(num);

}

//Ya tenemos relleno el listado, ahora vamos a ver los múltiplos de 5
//Guardamos el número de múltiplos en una variable numMult
int numMult=0;

for(int i = 0; i<100; i++)
{
    if(lisNum[i]%5 == 0) //Comprobamos que sea múltiplo de 5
        numMult++;
}

//Ahora calculamos el porcentaje
double porc = (double)numMult/100.0;

lblRespuesta.Text = porc + "%";
```

Comment: Hola lo intente hacer de tu manera y me sale un error: "No se puede aplicar la indizacion con [] a una expresión tipo 'ListBox' ".

Comment: Vale, es porque yo he llamado lstNumeros1 a una Lista de números, ahora lo edito y lo dejo arreglado.